# Problem managing two activities in Android

Tags: android, android-activity

What I am trying to do is very simple.  I created two classes A and B.  I created a click handler in A which calls a function in B which in turn calls a function in A.  In the called function in A I am create a button. My programs is being forced close when I try to push the button.

#### Class Loggs

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Loggs extends Activity {

    Model model;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    public void clickHandler(View v)
    {
        model = new Model();
        model.startGame();
        //click();
    }

    public void startGame()
    {
        Log.d("Log","Reached start game");
        click();
    }
    public void click()
    {
        Log.d("Log","Reached click");
        Button btn =(Button)findViewById(R.id.startButton);
        btn.setEnabled(false);
    }

}
```

#### Class Model

```
import android.app.Activity; import android.os.Bundle; import android.util.Log;


public class Model extends Activity{
    Loggs log;  

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }   

    public void startGame() {
        log= new Loggs();       
        Log.d("Logg","Reached start game Model");       
        log.startGame();    
    }
}
```

Comment: Circular dependencies should be avoided! Model has an instance of Logg and Logg an instance of Model. Also startGame() is called from Logg on the Model instance and this creates a second Logg instance and calls startGame(). Its really confusing... as only one Activity is visible at a time, its not clear why you call methods from one activity to another...

Comment: Also can you post the LogCat error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not really clear what you are trying to do here? Activities don't communicate with each other in this way. If you want one activity to start another you need to do so using Intents:

For example if you want to the Model activity from Loggs you would issue the following commands:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, Model.class);
this.startActivity(i);
```

Although I'm not sure if this is what you are trying to do. As has been already said you should avoid circular dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

is R.id.startButton in R.layout.main? Than.. you cannot instantiate an activity with new, imo, because the default constructor for activity are private (i think). Take a look at intent

Answer (score 0):

Look at the code. Doing "log = new Loggs();" does not call the "onCreate" method on Loggs. Which means that "setContentView" is never called.

At the Loggs#click method, the button that you get via "findViewById" will be null. As a result btn.setEnabled would cause a NullPointerException causing the program to crash.

WarrenFaith and blackbelt gives good advice. Read up on activities, when, how and why they should be used.